# Adding events to fullCalendar

Tags: javascript

I've installed FullCalendar in my Drupal 7 installation and can display it on a page but can't figure how to add events to the calendar display dates. I realize FullCalendar is a view but when I add fields to the view, even date fields, it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Somebody answered this in another question: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84977/full-calendar-how-to-add-events