# Full Calendar How to add Events

Tags: javascript

I'm using the [Full Calendar module](https://drupal.org/project/fullcalendar).It's all working fine, but I can't figure how to add events to it. I've read the docs, I can see you can set up a feed to a Google Calendar which is cool,but I want to enable the user to add events right there.

Comment: It is a good practice to read the actual "README" file included in the module, if any.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the documentation of the module it looks like you need create a custom content type with at least one date field and then create your view to use that content type.